# Is It possible to Fake Cookie and JavaScript using Curl?

Tags: php, cookies

How can i enable cookie and javasctipt in my curl request ?

Comment: Why do you want to fake a cookie?

Comment: he's trying to login via curl

Comment: Now it is clear that previous question was on breaking a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Yea i want to sighnup via curl ? whats wrong :|

Comment: so you're trying to spam this service? there is no conceivable reason to slam a service with an automated signup bot unless you're trying to abuse it.

Comment: Clouds FM terms of service: `[You agree not] to use any manual or automated means, including agents, robots, scripts, or spiders, to access or manage any user's account`

Comment: I am not going to abuse it ! i am coding scraper.

Comment: Clouds FM terms of service: `[You agree not to] Use automated means, including spiders, robots, crawlers, data mining tools, or the like to download data from this Network - except for Internet search engines (e.g. Google) and non-commercial public archives (e.g. archive.org) that comply with our robots.txt file, or "well-behaved" web services/RSS/Atom clients. We reserve the right to define what we mean by "well-behaved";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't do things like this.
There is a captcha on a site you're trying to login to.
That clearly signs that site owners **do not want bots** to login.
Please, have some corporate pride - do not break a fellow webmaster's site.

Comment: I am not gonna spam it :| i just wonder how cookie can be bypassed at http://snippets.bluejon.co.uk/check4-js-and-cookies/check4-js-and-cookie-enabled-v3-1.php

Comment: I could have changed the url with http://snippets.bluejon.co.uk/check4-js-and-cookies/check4-js-and-cookie-enabled-v3-1.php and asked the question..But i just wonder how to hide cookie :|

Comment: @VishnuSimbu - I severely doubt anyone here will want to help you break this sites terms of service. It's unethical.